# Make a progress bar vertical in new bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have  5 progress bar in boostrap they all animated(when you load page) but I would like to make the vertical this the code

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar six-sec-ease-in-out" aria-valuetransitiongoal="20"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info six-sec-ease-in-out" aria-valuetransitiongoal="40"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is custom boostrap code

```
.progress .progress-bar.six-sec-ease-in-out {
    -webkit-transition: width 6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: width 6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width 6s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 6s ease-in-out;             
 }
```

and for animation I used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).ready(function(e){
     $.each($('div.progress-bar'),function(){
       $(this).css('width', $(this).attr('aria-valuetransitiongoal')+'%');
     });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rotate elements in `CSS` with [`transform: rotate`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)

```
#yourSelector {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: it did work, just need to create another div and use transform: rotate (90)

Comment: this worked but my progress bar is in a bootstrap table and it doesn't re-size the row to fit the bar but it just draws it on top of the table. How can I achieve this, please?